# Why does $E=mc^2$ give results in Joules?

Tags: si-units, unit-conversion

Why does $E=mc^2$ give results in Joules ? Why didn't Einstein need to create a separate unit and how come using two standard units (speed of light in km.s and mass in grams) give another result in Joules ?

Comment: $c$ is the speed of light and therefore has units $m/s$. Hence, $mc^2$ has units $kg \cdot m^2 / s^2$ which is equivalent to a Joules.

Comment: Even if you don't feel like writing out the definition of J in terms of the base units, you can tell that $mc^2$ will have the same units of energy, by thinking about good old Newtonian kinetic energy. In Newtonian physics, kinetic energy is ${1\over 2}mv^2$. When we have a mass in kg and a speed in m/s, this quantity comes out in J. That means that $mc^2$ must come out in J too. After all, $v$ has the same units as $c$, and the $1\over 2$ has no units.

Comment: Indeed there is some magic inside -- Einstein's theories changed everything, but good old units were intact ;-)

Comment: Actually this raises an interesting question (for me at least) of why dimensional analysis always works. I mean, I completely believe that it does, I'm not doubting it; but I can't prove it, other than to say that it seems obvious to me that it should work.

Comment: @Colin: Dimensional analysis doesn't always work--you still have to combine variable meaningfully--http://xkcd.com/687/

Comment: @Jerry: You win 10 Internets for the XKCD reference.

Comment: Agree with @Colin :-) Anyway, Colin, I'm not sure exactly what you're getting at by saying you're not sure why dimensional analysis always works. If you can elaborate, that might be a good thing to ask as a separate question. (Or you could take it up in the chat room)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an energy.  The SI unit for energy is a Joule.  If the theory is going to predict an energy-mass correspondance, then it better give the energy in units of energy.  If the units of $mc^{2}$ didn't work out, for the equation to make any sense, you'd have to include some constant $\alpha$ so that $E=\alpha mc^{2}$ would have units of energy on both sides.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the definition of Joules in terms of the base kg/m/s units.

If you used lbs feet/second and calories you would need a conversion factor, because calories are defined in terms of heating water rather than mechanics, but the equation still works.

Answer (score 1):

So this had always puzzled me, until last night.

Here I'm going to try and describe my reason for confusion, and explain how I overcame it. Physicists I met could never explain this to me in a way that made sense to me. It was obvious to them. I imagine in years to come I will find this hard to explain, as it will seem obvious to me too. I apologise if the following seems over-simplistic for some.

The issue for me was that the key units for mass and speed were chosen for historical reasons.

- A metre is some arbitrary scale factor $(4 \times 10^7)^{-1}$ times some ancient estimate of the circumference of the earth.
- A second is some arbitrary scale factor $(24 \times 60 \times 60)^{-1}$ times the average period of the earth's rotation.
- A kilogram is the mass of an arbitrary fixed volume $(1000cm^3)$ of an arbitrary fluid (water).

I could believe that $E=\alpha mc^2$, but it seemed very far-fetched that $\alpha$ worked out as exactly 1, given the arbitrary historical choices for the units of mass/length/time.

Now, I still cannot tell you why $\alpha=1$ (I guess I'd need to understand GR for that), but I now can hopefully explain in simple terms why the arbitrary choice of units doesn't affect $\alpha$. If, for example, a kilogram had been defined completely differently back in the day, we would have got the same value for alpha.

The key thing, as others have mentioned, is understanding the definition of the Joule.

A Newton is the forced required to accelerate a $1kg$ mass at $1ms^{-2}$. (One Newton is defined as 1 $kg.m.s^{-2}$)

A Joule is the energy required to apply one Newton of force for 1 metre. (One Joule is defined as 1 $kg.m^2.s^{-2}$)

---

Now for a thought experiment:

Imagine now you had a $20kg$ rock. You write $20kg$ on the side.

The amount of energy required to accelerate this rock by $1ms^{-2}$ for $1m$ is $20J$ (from the above definition of Joule).

Now imagine you had a battery which held exactly this much energy. You write $20J$ on the side.

Einstein has (in our confused world) told us that the total energy in your rock is $20\alpha c^2 J$.

This could be stored in exactly $\alpha c^2$ of these batteries. Imagine then you had such a pile of batteries.

For the rest of this thought experiment hang on to the same stone, and the same pile of $\alpha c^2$ batteries.

Now, imagine you took your rock and your batteries into a parallel universe, where the only difference was that the kilogram had instead been defined all those years ago as the mass of $1000cm^3$ of another substance: gold. Gold is $20\times$ more dense than water.

Whoever came along and defined the Newton and the Joule, would have defined them in the same way. But when you compared them to the units in our own universe, they would of course be $20 \times$ larger than our own units (see the definitions above).

So now go back and look at your rock and your pile of $\alpha c^2$ batteries.

You would now weigh your rock with the local scales, and relabel it as a $1kg$ rock.

You could measure the energy in your labelled battery (maybe by accelerating your rock at $1ms^{-2}$ for $1m$). You would find that it was 1 (local) Joule and label it as such.

Of course, the number of your batteries required to hold the total energy in your rock hasn't changed. It's still $\alpha c^2$ batteries.

In this parallel universe, the total energy in your $1kg$ rock is $1 \alpha c^2 J$. And so we see that $E=\alpha mc^2$ in this universe too.

---

You can try similar thought experiments where the metre, or the second, or both are redefined in the parallel universe.

So now its blindingly obvious to me that the archaic choice of units doesn't matter, $\alpha$ will always be the same provided that the Joule is defined correctly. (Across all our parallel universes, the capacity of battery required to hold a (local) Joule is proportional to the mass chosen to be the local unit mass.)

I'm still not clear why $\alpha=1$, but I'm much happier now I can see why those arbitrary ancient decisions for the base units aren't important.

One final observation, at school we learnt why (using SI units) kinetic energy = $0.5mv^2J$. And that's not hard to understand. So given that the speed of light is some important "maximum speed" of the universe, if someone had told me the total energy was $0.5mc^2$, I wouldn't have been looking for some arbitrary constant to compensate for the choice of units.